CMake project with WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS fails to build .PYDs from the first attempt
I use the WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS property in a CMake project to port it on Windows. CMake successfully generates the build files using the Visual Studio 17 2022 generator. It can build normal Dynamic Link Library (.dll) modules from the first attempt. For the Python Dynamic Module (.pyd) modules, I need to run the build twice as it failed on the first attempt.
The issue boils down to the pre-linker action batch script that CMake embeds into .vcxproj files. For some reason, it fails at executing the command: cmake.exe -E __create_def _my_py_module_.dir/Release/exports.def _my_py_module_.dir/Release/objects.txt.
Error: error MSB3073: The command "_EMBEDDED_BATCH_SCRIPT_HERE_" exited with code -1073741819.
The CMake command create_def doesn't seem to be documented. I wonder if someone else came across this issue and managed to fix it. Thanks!
